# spool for insert in sql developer not working

Tags: sql, oracle, file, insert, spool

I have below select query for which the result of this query i want to create insert scripts and saved it in files. I have used spool.

```
set long 10000  
set lines 100000  
set sqlformat insert  
spool c:\temp\Insert_TEST_GRP.sql  
select ID,NAME,TEST_DATE from TEST_GRP sd  
where TEST_DATE =  
 ( select min(TEST_DATE)  
   from TEST_GRP sd2  
   where sd.ID = sd2.ID     
 )  
and sd.TEST_DATE <> TO_DATE ('01.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy');  
spool off
```

The file has been created. But when i view the file i am getting the result which is not in the form of insert statements as i want to run this insert statement again.

Below hows the data looks like in file which looks in incorrect format:
[image]

Comment: Maybe show us the incorrectly formatted data, and what you are expecting?

Comment: Also maybe mention which version of SQL Developer you're using, and how you're viewing the spooled file. Do you get an error from `set sqlformat insert` perhaps, if you're on a very old version?

Comment: thanks Alex i understood the issue is with my SQL developer version. I am running older version i.e v3.0. But when i checked now in higher version it works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have access to your table or your data.

But here it is working with the demo schema HR and its EMPLOYEES table

```
set sqlformat insert
spool c:\users\jdsmith\desktop\SO_inserts.sql
select * from employees;
spool off
```

[image]

You're using SET LONG - does your table have LOBS in it?

Also, I noticed you asked this same question on the [OTN Forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4072912)...

Comment: i have removed set long 10000 , set lines 100000  but still not getting the result in proper format. I have mentioned in my question the result i am getting

Comment: Without your TEST_GRP table and data, it will be impossible for us to help you.

Comment: can you please tell me how are you running it in sql developer ? I am running it using F5 key. I am getting the result but the result format is not correct.

Comment: With F5. Why are you ignoring my request?

Comment: Sorry i am not ignoring your request. As you said i have removed set long. Do you need actual data ?

Comment: thanks i understood the issue is with my SQL developer version. I am running older version i.e v3.0. But when i checked now in higher version it works perfectly

Comment: No, I asked if your data had LOBS - a BLOB or a CLOB - the problem here very well could be data dependent. I've asked for your data, because yes, I need it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff it  works now the problem was with my sql developer version

Answer (score 2):

The `set sqlformat` method to format your query results [was added in version 4.1](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/).

If you're on an earlier version (e.g. 3.0 as you said in a comment) then it would complain, which you seem to have overlooked; e.g. in 4.0:

```
set sqlformat insert
```

gets this in the script output window:

```
line 1: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set sqlformat insert
```

The `/*insert*/` method was available earlier than that:

```
select /*insert*/ * from dual;
```

which gets

```
REM INSERTING into dual
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into "dual" (DUMMY) values ('X');
```

(don't really attempt to insert into `dual`, of course). You can also use the export wizard (tools->database export); or run your query with control-enter, right-click on the output grid and choose 'export' (though [it may repeat the query](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/03/how-to-export-sql-developer-query-results-without-re-running-the-query/)).

Upgrading to the current version is the sensible thing to do though.

Comment: Your code examples suggest that your are using sqlplus. I'm positive that that sqlformat command works in sqlcl. The source quoted also uses sqlci, but imho doesn't make it explicit enough: "Now that we have our own SQL*Plus command line interface (AKA SQLcl),..."

Comment: @Arman - no, this was using SQL Developer, which is what the question was about. The "SQLPLUS" in the error message is because SQL Developer recognises most SQL\*Plus syntax but that old version didn't understand `set sqlformat` - neither does SQL\*Plus of course - but it was just a generic message for any `set` it didn't know. SQLcl didn't exist when SQL Developer 3.0 was released, I believe. But `sqlformat` works in both SQLcl and SQL Developer (from version 4.1 anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a string that is the INSERT statement formatted with the columns you need.  Example

```
set long 10000  
set lines 100000  
set sqlformat insert  
spool c:\temp\Insert_TEST_GRP.sql  
select 'INSERT INTO TEST_GRP (ID,NAME,TEST_DATE) VALUES (' ||
     ID||','||NAME||',' || TEST_DATE||');'
 from TEST_GRP sd  

where TEST_DATE =  
 ( select min(TEST_DATE)  
   from TEST_GRP sd2  
   where sd.ID = sd2.ID     
 )  
and sd.TEST_DATE <> TO_DATE ('01.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy');  
spool off
```

If you are using sqldeveloper, then you can just use the built-in export function and export the result grid as inserts.

Comment: The `set sqlformat insert ` should mean you don't need to manually construct the insert statements. (And if you do, you need to consider adding single- and double-quotes around strings, date formats, etc.)

Comment: thanks its working but when i view the insert statement and tried to run it i am getting error as SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma. There is date column and in values field its not taken as string but just like number format as 17-JAN-17 12.00.00. How can i make it string ?

Answer (score 1):

I used SQL Developer. Make sure to click **Run script(F5)** instead of run statement.

---

For multi statement in sample file use **"/"** between statement.

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
set sqlformat insert
spool C:\Necessary_file\Reqular_task\QDE\profile_const.sql
select * from export_profile where profile_name='SPS_DIAG';
/
select * from profile_const where profile_name='SPS_DIAG';
/
select * from profile_panel where profile_name='SPS_DIAG' order by 5
/
spool off
```

[image]